# Lync in VBA: Method MyServiceId failed

Tags: excel, lync, vba

I am using MS Lync 2010 and I am trying to executie a simple procedure in VBA to check the status of a Lync user:

```
Public Sub User_Status_OCS()
    Dim myOCS As New CommunicatorAPI.Messenger 'Office Communicator API
    Dim OCS_User_Mail_ID As String
    Dim curr_status As Integer
    Dim flag As Integer
    Dim stat As String
    stat = ""
    OCS_User_Mail_ID = "test@test.com" 'Change the Mail ID to USER Mail.
    curr_status = myOCS.GetContact(OCS_User_Mail_ID, myOCS.MyServiceId).Status'ERROR HERE
    If curr_status = 34 Then stat = "Away"
    If curr_status = 10 Then stat = "Busy"
    If curr_status = 18 Then stat = "Idle"
    If curr_status = 1 Then stat = "Offline"
    If curr_status = 2 Then stat = "Online"
    If curr_status = 0 Then stat = "Unknown"

    MsgBox "User:" & OCS_User_Mail_ID & " OCS Status = " & stat
End Sub
```

Unfortunately this piece of code `myOCS.MyServiceId` throws the following error:
[image]

I added a reference to Microsoft Communicator API 2007 and I can't seem to find the source of this issue. MS Lync 2010 is also running in the background.

Please help me diagnose the problem.

Comment: Try using the [ServiceID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff801454(v=vs.85).aspx) property instead of MyServiceID property.  A note at the top of the [page for the MyServiceID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff801486(v=vs.85).aspx) property page on MSDN says _The MyServiceId property is available for use in Windows Messenger 5.0. It may be unavailable in subsequent versions. Use ServiceID instead_

Comment: No such property available. What is more the documentation says that: [ServiceID is no longer available in Windows Vista. See Windows Messenger for more information.]

Comment: As mentioned in my comment above - no such property (ServiceID) is available.